# what is it in the Bundle class in android studio

Tags: java

I've recently started learning Android (after completing Java EE), and come across a reference variable (`savedInstanceState`) of a class named `Bundle`, passed as an argument in the method called `onCreate`. I've been pondering upon it for quite a while and cannot find any relevant answer! Help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: It's the bundle that you modify in `savedInstanceState()` on orientation changes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-android-activity-state-using-save-instance-state

Comment: This can help you: https://content.pivotal.io/blog/android-savedinstancestate-bundle-faq

Comment: @muazhud Thank you! it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

`onCreate` method is responsible to launch the activity and bundle class is a kind of data structure which stores the data used previously if some disturbance occurs in during using that activity (like you rotated the phone if someone called you  ) with the help of reference variable `savedinstancestate` and you can now access the previous data that means you will start from there where picked up the phone.